# How to implement inheritance like behavior in Rust?

Tags: rust

I come from Java/C# background and inheritance is an important concept in there, and it's such an important feature in so many use cases. Need to know, how to get around it in Rust.

I know, Rust doesn't support inheritance directly.

Comment: When you want OOP, then Rust is probably not the language that you should use. When watching [this](https://youtu.be/IRTfhkiAqPw), you may understand what I mean.

Comment: Hello, i suggest you to read the following documentation, [Rust OOP](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is not an "OOP" language, however it has some [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html) of OOP languages. Trying to write code that you would write in Java or C# in Rust will result in nothing, but confusion and suffering.

While in general Rust encourages to use [composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance), you could you could use traits and [super traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) to express inheritance-like relation between interfaces (and not objects themselves).